# Magento 2.1 - How override /vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/shipping.html

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, template, overrides

I want override this:

```
/vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/shipping.html
```

I use Magento 2.1

Answer (score 1):

You can copy this the file that you want to override to the same directory of your theme.
For example, I want to override this file

```
Magento/Tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/shipping.html
```

and my theme's name is Wtx. I will copy shipping.html to

```
Wtx/Tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/shipping.html.
```

Answer (score 0):

To override the file, you need to copy that file to your theme.

Ex:
Suppose the theme is ABC/abc where `ABC` is the theme vendor and `abc` is the theme.

Create the file as follows:  `app/design/frontend/ABC/abc/Magento_Tax/template/checkout/summary/shipping.html`

This will override the module PHTML file.